# Shared element transition not working in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-animation, android-cardview

I've set my app style

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

Set the transition name in the image from the cardview

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pet_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_name"/>
```

Set the transition name in the image in the second activity

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="566dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_name"
    />
```

And set the onClick listener for the card to this for shared element transition

```
//animation
        String transitionName = v.getResources().getString(R.string.transition_name);
        View viewStart = v.findViewById(R.id.entire_card);
        ActivityOptionsCompat options =
                ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity)mContext, viewStart, transitionName);

        v.getContext().startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

But when I click on a cardview to view the second activity, the animation does not run. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

How have you bind **pet_image** in the activity/fragment?

You can try this way :

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options =
                ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity)mContext, 
                                      (View) pet_image, "transitionName");
```

Comment: Which android version device are you using?

Comment: Your above code is saying you are using entire_card for transition and in your layout of first activity, you have given the transition for pet_image. Fix that and check out.

Comment: It's high enough to use the shared element transition, I had another app that used this as well and it shows the transition on the same device.

Comment: Checkout the above comment.

Comment: You're right, I changed it so that I give the correct transition for pet_image instead of entire_card but it still isn't working

Comment: Are these view common element name in both activities? Also can you check setting visibility to visible for the pet_image?

Answer (score 0):

If a shared element is nested inside of another view, you need to make sure that the parent view is also transitioned.
[image]